# "The value you enter isn’t valid for this field" - cannot be triggered by ribbon command

Tags: ms-access

I have below two different controls.

1. Combo Box (CB) control which Record Source is query and limited to
   List with "On Not In List" Event code.
2. Text Box (TB) control which is bounded to Integer control source.

I have question for error handler when data entry is incorrect on these two controls.

1. CB - "On Not In List" Event will be triggered if data entered is incorrect and press tab to move out focus. Instead of press tab to move out focus, I click ribbon command and Event will be triggered also.
2. TB - System error message "The value you enter isn’t valid for this field" will be shown when entering non-numerical character and press tab to move out focus. Error message will **NOT** show up when I click ribbon command.

Question:

1. For TB control, can I disable system error message "The value you enter isn’t valid
   for this field" and replaced by my own error handler which will be
   trigged when click ribbon command?
2. If system error cannot be disable, how to trig "The value you enter isn’t valid
   for this field" error message when click ribbon
   command?

Comment: Use control's BeforeUpdate event to do data validation. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Yes, I have BeforeUpdate Event.  For bounded integer TB, BeforeUpdate Event will be trigged, if data entered is number, for example "12".  It will not be trigged, if I enter "W12" to bounded integer TB.  "W12" will trig "The value you enter isn’t valid for this field" only when I press tab to move out focus.  I am okay for "The value you enter isn’t valid for this field".  But, "The value you enter isn’t valid for this field" does not shows up when I click ribbon command.

Comment: Just did a test. Added BeforeUpdate code to a textbox. I get the standard "The value you entered ..." message even when clicking ribbon. I am not getting the BeforeUpdate event when entry is not valid. It's been a while since I tested this event. I had not recalled that. So, it appears cannot get around the standard message for invalid input. And again, I get the message even when clicking ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

For the combobox NotInList event, there are two parameters:  NewData as String and Response as Integer.  To suppress the ugly "The value you entered isn't valid..." prompt, simply add the line of code:  Response = 0

```
    Private Sub YourFieldName_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
       Response = 0
       '---Additional code if desired.  For me, in the form footer, 
       '   I use a label called, lblHelper and set the caption using 
       '   a custom string to visually show the user there is an error.
         
       lblHelper.Caption = "Error: You must select a value from the list."
    End Sub
```

For the textbox, use the BeforeUpdate event.  Set the parameter 'Cancel' to true and perform a logical test to determine if the field is a real number.  The IsNumeric function is built into VBA and returns either True or False.

```
 Private Sub txtYourTextField_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If IsNumeric(txtYourField.Text) = False Then
        lblHelper.Caption = "Error: invalid data"
        Cancel = True  ' or use Cancel = -1
        Beep
        '---Remember True and False are boolean data types.  In MS Access VBA, 
        '   you can assign integer values of 0 (False) and -1 (True) respectively 
        '   without having syntax or run-time errors.
     End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use the KeyPress Event.  Simply use a Select statement to evalauate the ASCII code.  If the case is not equal to the ASCII values of 0-9, then use:

> DoCmd.CancelEvent